# Heat equation - Evans

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, weak-derivatives

I have the following question. In Evan's PDE book it is stated (p 345, section 6.61) that if we take the differnential operator:
$$
Lu=-\Delta u +cu
$$
then there exists a $\mu>0$ such that for all $c\ge -\mu$ the operator satisfies the requirements for the Lax-Milgram theorem and thus there exist a unique solution to the associated boundary value problem.
My problem is that for $c<0$ and some domain like $(-1,1)$ we can always find an eigenvector of that operator and thus there does not exist a solution, by tthe Fredholm alternative. So what am I doing wrong here?
These two statements are contradiction each other...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Poincare inequality, we have
$$(Lu,u)=|u|^2_{H^1}-\mu\|u\|_{2}^2\ge (1-C\mu)|u|_{H^1}^2,$$
so as long as $C\mu<1$, the operator is coercive. This coercivity (as well as boundedness etc.) tells us that there exists a unique solution, so as long as the assumption is satisfied, Fredholm alternative does not hold. If you don't restrict $\mu$ you can find an example where Fredholm alternative holds.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point at all. The question is, when $c$ (or $\mu$) is negative (no matter how negative), I get two solutions to the equation $Lu=0$ for a domain like $(-1,1)$. How does that comply with the uniqueness? @ellya

Comment: You shouldn't for certain ranges of $\mu<0$, more precisely, if the poincare constant is given by $C$, and $0>\mu>-\frac{1}{C}$, then the operator is coercive, and the Lax Milgram theorem gives existence and uniqueness. Note that on $(-1,1)$ the Poincare constant is something like $1/2$.

Comment: Apologies as well, I had an incorrect sign in what I wrote, which may have been misleading

Comment: Hi @ellya, thank you very much. My issue is that the functions $u(x)=\sin(\sqrt{2\lambda})$ and $u=0$ solve the equation $-1/2\Delta u -\lambda u=0$  on $(0,\pi)$ as long $\lambda>0$. But you say that for certain values there exist a unique solution.

Comment: True, the solution is $u=\sin(\sqrt{2\lambda}x)$, but that only satisfies $u(\pi)=0$ for a certain discrete set of values of $\lambda$, namely the eigenvalues, so if we take $\lambda$ smaller than the first eigenvalue then we are fine.

Comment: Also the Poincare constant is given by the smallest eigenvalue.

Comment: ah, this is what i was missing! Thank you so much ! @ellya

Comment: No problem, happy to help.